# How do I detect if an SKSpriteNode has been touched

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch, skspritenode, touchesbegan

I am trying to detect if my sprite node has been touched and I have no idea where to start.

```
let Pineapple = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pineappleimg")
Pineapple.userInteractionEnabled = true
Pineapple.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 200, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
self.addChild(Pineapple)
```

Comment: This question can be used as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840042/cant-tap-skspritenode-no-touch-detected-ios

Answer (score 80, accepted):

First set the `name` property of the `SKSpriteNode` to a string.

```
pineapple.name = "pineapple"
pineapple.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

then in `touchesBegan` function in the `Scene`

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
    let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        if name == "pineapple"
        {
            print("Touched")
        }
    }

}
```

This is one way to do it.
You can also subclass `SKSpriteNode` and override the `touchesBegan` inside it.

```
class TouchableSpriteNode : SKSpriteNode
{
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        print("touched")
    }
}
```

Then do

```
let pineapple = TouchableSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pineappleimg")
pineapple.userInteractionEnabled = true
pineapple.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 200, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
self.addChild(pineapple)
```

Comment: Fails to compile in swift 3.

Comment: **Swift4.1**. override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch:UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch
        let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)
        
        if let name = touchedNode.name
        {
            if name == "pineapple"
            {
                print("Touched")
            }
        }
        
    }

Answer (score 21):

If you are looking only for a few nodes that can be touched (e.g., the "Continue" or "Exit" labels in a game UI), this might be an alternative but very simple solution:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    if myNode.containsPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)) {
        print("touched")
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this differentiate between Continue and Exit labels?

Comment: might be... maybe... that you're suggesting this code be in both labels, Continue and Exit, and that one of them will be called when touchesBegun information is sent to it... because it's registered for the touch information by virtue of over-riding touchesBegun. Is that right, or am I...

Comment: Of course this will not work properly for overlapping or intersecting labels but touchesBegan() is meant to be overridden for the whole scene and is not a method of a label.

Comment: So touchesBegun() can only exist in scene classes?

Comment: In fact it's inherited by UIResponder: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan ... which is the superclass of UIView. SKScene contains an SKView which inherits from UIView :)

Comment: So all SKSpriteNodes are UIResponders?

Comment: I've just learnt that ALL SKNodes have UIResponder as conformed protocol. Which I think means just about any node can ask to be called when its touched. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Yes - if they contain something visible. An SKNode could contain several e.g. SKSpriteNodes and when one of these SKSpriteNodes is touched their own touchesBegan()-Method is called and not the one of the parent SKNode.

Answer (score 12):

Update for Swift Swift version **3.0.2** (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1) and XCode Version **8.2.1** (8C1002):

> Value of type 'Set' has no member '**anyObject**'
>
> '**locationInNode**' has been renamed to 'location(in:)'
>
> '**nodeAtPoint**' has been renamed to 'atPoint(_:)'

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "myNodeName" {
            print("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This will detect touches in **Xcode 9.2 Swift 4.0**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        if name == "playLbl"
        {
            print("playLbl Touched")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Won't `touches.first` miss some use cases when nodes overlap each other as [Florian mentions for another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922198/how-do-i-detect-if-an-skspritenode-has-been-touched#comment66915131_34466773)?

Answer (score 7):

**swift 5** update

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchedNode = self.nodes(at: location)
            for node in touchedNode {
                if node.name == "play_button" {
                    startGame()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Implement `touchesBegan` method that is called when a touch begins. Alternatively you can do this in `touchesEnded` as well.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(location)

    for node in nodes
    {
        if node.name == "youNodeName"
        {
            // Node tapped
            // Do something

            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3** answer which embeds touch functionality in subclass of `SKSpriteNode`:

```
class SpriteSub: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    ...

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch!")
    }

}
```

Comment: Crashalot it's still making me put in the NSCoder init... I forgot how to properly override this thing x{

Comment: @Fluidity yes you need that too

Comment: @Fluidity updated again. also UIColor.clear() from your edit is not Swift 3 code.

Comment: Crashalot yeah I caught that too my bad

Comment: Crashalot I'm starting to feel like an idiot now because I know I've done this before....

`let sprite = SpriteSub()` is getting me a bunch of nothing, and autocomplete shows nothing other than the `coder:` init...

Comment: @Fluidity it's nothing because UIColor.clear is transparent. Try UIColor.red.

Comment: Crashalot yeah Ima go get a beer now. I was trying to instantiate it in the SKScene field section (it wasn't the color). Upvoting now :) hashtag idiotdeveloper ---->

Answer (score 4):

Use this piece of code to detect touch on SKSpriteNode

```
if(nodeAtPoint(location) == node){



}
```

Comment: Simplest answer EVER!  Thank you :)

Comment: This works but only if the node in question does not overlap with other nodes, right?

Comment: For comparing classes, shouldn't you use `===` and not `==`?

Comment: @mogelbuster yes it seems === is correct if you're doing identity equality. details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44222407/144088

Answer (score 1):

Update for Swift 3.0 and XCode 7.3.1. I've got a SKShapeNode that I've derived to a new class and inserted it on the Scene.  When I want to detect this object it I check as follows:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(location)

        for node in nodes
        {
            if node is SKNodeDerivedNode
            {
                NSLog("Touch a SKNodeDerivedNode")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have still not got your sprite to work even after subclassing `SKSpriteNode`, you most likely forgot to add `node.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` when you initialise it!

This allows `touchesBegan(_:with:)` to be called, as you can now interact with the node.

---

Example:

```
node = MySprite(texture: texture, size: size)
node.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I use in Swift 4 to find if there is a touch in a specific type of node:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }
    let touchPosition = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNodes = nodes(at: touchPosition)
    for node in touchedNodes {
        if let nodoTouched = node as? YourNodeType {
            // touched!
        }
    }
}
```