# How detect which sprites I touch

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, swift-playground

I'm generating a grid of bricks (SKSpriteNode) in a for loop like this:

```
for row in 0..<numRows
    {
        for col in 0..<numColumns
        {
            let brick = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: brickWidth, height: brickHeight))

            brick.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
            brick.name = "brick_d" 
            brick.position = CGPoint(x: brickFirstXPosition + col * 65, y: brickFirstYPosition + row * 65)

            self.addChild(brick)
        }
    }
```

Now I don't know how distinguish one node from another, I have to do this according to their different position or something else?
Practically I need to touch one specific node with a touchesBegan func. for doing things according to the node properties (bg, image contained, etc.)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27922198/1430420

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect if an SKSpriteNode has been touched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922198/how-do-i-detect-if-an-skspritenode-has-been-touched)

Answer (score 2):

Use `touchesBegan()`:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first // get the first touch
        let touchedNode = selectNodeForTouch(touch.location(in: self))
        // do stuff with your 'touchedNode'
    }
```