# SpriteKit: how do I detect tap on an SKLabelNode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

**SpriteKit**: How do I detect the tap on a `SKLabelNode` and perform some action?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect if an SKSpriteNode has been touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922198/how-do-i-detect-if-an-skspritenode-has-been-touched)